# Tensorflow multiplication broadcasting within batches

Tags: tensorflow

We know that tf.multiply can broadcast like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
a = tf.Variable(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4))
b = tf.Variable(np.arange(4))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.multiply(a, b))
```

This will give us

```
[[0, 1, 4, 9],
 [0, 5, 12, 21],
 [0, 9, 20, 33]]
```

But my question is, what should I do if both `a` and `b` are in batches? That is,

```
a = tf.Variable(np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4))
b = tf.Variable(np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4))
```

Then how can I get the result of multiplying (broadcasting) the vector onto the matrix in each batch? Like the following answer:

```
[[[0, 1, 4, 9],
  [0, 5, 12, 21],
  [0, 9, 20, 33]],

 [[48, 65, 84, 105],
  [64, 85, 108, 133],
  [80, 105, 132, 161]]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasting first adds singleton dimensions to the left until rank is matched. In first case that adds batch dimension. But in second case you already have batch dimension so you need to insert singleton dimension manually in the second position:

```
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(24), (2, 3, 4))
b = tf.reshape(tf.range(8), (2, 4))
sess.run(tf.mul(a, tf.expand_dims(b, 1)))
```